# Firebase: Oncancelled method fired after calling firebaseAuth signout

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

In Android activity `onCreate()` method, a firebase reference is invoked on  addvalieEventListener() as shown below.

The callbacks are working as expected however,when `FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();` is called via options menu, `onCancelled()` is fired, why?

```
dbref.child("users").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
 @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            Log.e(TAG,"a ERROR:"+databaseError.toString());

        }
    });
```

optionsmenu snippets

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.sign_out_menu: // preferences settings
        {
            Toast.makeText(this, "signout", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();

            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences("test",MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
            editor.putBoolean("Active",false);
            editor.commit();

            Intent intent = new Intent(ProfileviewActivity.this, SignInActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }
        break;

    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Please share the code from your menu.

Comment: @AlexMamo, added code snippet

Comment: As i see in your code, there is no relation between the listener and the menu. Maybe when you start the new activity, you are calling the listener again. Is this what cause the problem?